# How to properly chain futures with firebase transaction on flutter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

Here is my code. the succes returns `false` because documents lenght is 0.

```
   var sucess = await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      await transaction.set(userReference, userMap);
    }).then((_) {
      return Firestore.instance.collection(CollectionName.user).where(FirebaseUserField.uid, isEqualTo: userMap["uid"]).getDocuments();
    }).then((querySnapshot) {
      if (querySnapshot.documents.length == 0) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    });
```

This code goes into my second future where I query the database for user that I just updated with previous transaction.
I would like to chain everything with futures to make it simple for error checking.

From the Firestore docs I can see that the handler resolves to, I think, return value of the transaction, but the instance that calls the transaction resolves to empty map.

`runTransaction((Transaction) → Future<dynamic> transactionHandler, {Duration timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5)}) → Future<Map<String, dynamic>>`

What is the proper way to call the next future after the transaction is finished, or to go into error if it fails.

One thing to consider is that when I debug with a breakpoint where I query for the user, so there is a delay, I get the user correctly.

Also user is correctly written to my database.

EDIT: I also tried

```
var sucess = await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      return transaction.set(userReference, userMap);
    })
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the nested `await` inside your transaction, which would also explain the race condition you see during debug.

What happens when you use this transaction handler in `runTransaction`?

```
(transaction) {
  return transaction.set(userReference, userMap);
}
```

Comment: the same, already tried that. After some thinking it seems that the race condition has to do with firebase server, the transaction ends on the client, and immediately it starts new request to get the document, but the firebase server takes time as well to process the transaction. That is just my guess for now.

Comment: I just read the documentation, when transaction completes, it is definite, and the data is written.

Comment: Have you tried not making the transaction handler async and just returning `transaction.set`? In your edit the handler is still async.

Comment: havent tried, but as far as I remember from the docs, async function are not spawned as microtransactions anymore

Comment: I will try to do it

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the Futures with awaiting. Try removing the first await before `Firestore.instance.runTransaction`

```
var sucess = Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      await transaction.set(userReference, userMap);
    }).then((_) {
      return Firestore.instance.collection(CollectionName.user).where(FirebaseUserField.uid, isEqualTo: userMap["uid"]).getDocuments();
    }).then((querySnapshot) {
      if (querySnapshot.documents.length == 0) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    });
```

You may need to also remove the `await` from `await transaction.set(userReference, userMap);` since that will return immediately with a future but not 100% sure